# Android get layout height and width in a fragment

Tags: android, layout, fragment, dimension

I am working on a fragment and I want to get the dimension of a `layout` contained in the `xml` `fragment layout`.
When I try the code

```
RelativeLayout myLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
myLayout.getHeight();
```

it returns 0.
I need these dimensions to put inside myLayout other objects.

I try to use:

```
myLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener( 
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener(){

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            mHeight = myLayout.getHeight();  
            mWidth= myLayout.getWidth();
            System.out.println("width: "+mWidth+"   height: "+mHeight);
         }
});
```

but this code is invoke a lot of time and I don't know exactly when it is execute.
I need these dimensions into  `public void onActivityCreated ()` method. Is it possible?

Comment: what is myLayout..mention that code

Comment: It si reference of a relative layout declared in XML

Comment: post mylayout xml file

Answer (score 38):

There's a cleaner solution to this, just use the `View.post()` method on your fragment's root view, and you can call `getMeasuredHeight()/getMeasuredWidth()` and get the actual values.

E.g.

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment, container, false);

    root.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // for instance
            int height = root.getMeasuredHeight(); 
        }
    });

    return root;
}
```

Very neat and tidy and no messy mucking about with the `ViewTreeObserver`.

I've only tested this with android-23 devices, but the API has had this method since level 1.

Anyway, WFM.

Comment: I think you can use onViewCreated if you need the measure from the fragment class and not from the activity

Comment: @FernandoGallego No, in `onViewCreated` width and height return 0.

Comment: Is this documented behavior?

Comment: @funct7 is what documented? That getMeasuredHeight() isn't available until it's visible or View.post?

Answer (score 11):

The addOnGlobalLayoutListener will be called whenever small change of the view happened. So you need to remove this listener from the view.

Simple usage:

```
public static void removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(View v, ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener listener){
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
    v.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(listener);
} else {
    v.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
}
```

}

I would suggest you to check :

```
if (myLayout.getHeight()>0 && myLayout.getWidth()>0) {
// Do some code...
removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(..)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In `onActivityCreated`, the view hasn't been measured yet.

So no, you can't get the measurements from there. `onGlobalLayout` is a good place to do it. Layouts happen directly after measurement.

You can remove your listener afterwards, if you only want to do it once. Note that layouts can change size though (soft keyboards appearing, for example)