# android Fragments onFocusChanges

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, onfocus

I have some code which I run in normal activities in method `onFocusChanges`, it is important to run it just there as the code requires the activity to be loaded first as it get images width and heights from the view:

**in MainActivity**

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        SizeModifier sizeModifier = SizeModifier.getInstance(this);
        sizeModifier.adjust
    }
```

so all this is working just fine, the problem is this main view contains a fragment changes according to button press like that

> ```
>     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
>     fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_view_fragment,fragment).commit();
> ```

the fragment of course has activity and xml, I want now when the fragment open to run the previous code when focus changes but the problem is fragments does not have `onFocusChange`, I tried all `onStart` `onResume` `onCreateActivity` 
but non seems to work as I want, of course the method is called but all images widths are returned 0,
so is there away to be sure that images will return correct width or some alternative to `onFocusChanges`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I found what could do the purpose, 
simply for fragments we add this simple code to the `onCreateView` after inflating the view like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater .inflate(R.layout.activity_courses_fragment, container, false);
    // >>>> this is the thread which will run when every thing is ready 
    rootView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // >>> this method now can get width with no problems
            SizeModifier.getInstance(getContext()).adjust(rootView);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

special thanks to @Staffan for this idea as solution for another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937953/android-get-layout-height-and-width-in-a-fragment)